# Magento 2 - Configurable product get all options and for out of stock add product alert

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3, out-of-stock

How can I display all configurable options including the products which are **out of stock**?

Also, for out of stock products can we set **notify me when in stock** as it is done for simple products?

I am using `Magento 2.3`

Can this me done by setting system configuration or programmatically?

Comment: do you want to done it programmatically ?

Comment: Yes, if not by system config. As I didn't find a way by setting configurations.

Comment: you need to build complete module to done all your tasks, they are not done by a single piece of code

Comment: Is there any similar module available on GIT, please share.

Comment: ok if i will find it free, i will definitely share it with you

Comment: https://github.com/pkarsai/show-out-of-stock-products-magento2 with that you can get to show the out of stock options, im also looking for the alert subscription to the simple products

Answer (score 0):

i want to show popup the product is out of stock when customer login??plz help me